# Python Pandas to_html can't print utf-8 characters

Tags: python, pandas

I have some UTF 8 characters that I am trying to print out but when I issue the following code

```
csv = 'name\n"BOVÉR, LIÙSAIDH"'
`df = pandas.DataFrame.from_csv( StringIO(csv), index_col=False, encoding='utf-8')
print df.to_html()
```

I get an error as follows

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xc9' in position 260: ordinal not in range(128)

I tried adding the force unicode flag but that didn't change anything. Any tips?

Comment: Works for me on python 3.4 using pandas 0.15.2 are you using python 2?

Comment: Here's a small discussion on [the issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/891) back from 2012 that's been closed.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not precise enough to provide a definitive answer.  Questions on file and string encodings, pandas version and where that particular error comes from remain.  But there is enough there to construct an MCVE to evaluate the issue on python and python3 interpreters.

Couple things to go after:

- `from_csv()` is obsolete in recent pandas.  Use `read_csv()` as early
  as feasible given the version of pandas being used
- The PEP-0263 source file encoding so that the MCVE can work
- Make the test data a unicode string

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
import sys

print(sys.version)
print(pd.__version__)

csv = u'name\n"BOVÉR, LIÙSAIDH"'
print(type(csv))
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv), index_col=False, encoding='utf-8')
print(df.to_html())
```

python2.7 run:

```
python unicode_to_html.py 
2.7.16 (default, Mar 19 2019, 10:44:02) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)]
0.20.3
<type 'unicode'>
...snip...
      <td>BOVÉR, LIÙSAIDH</td>
...snip...
```

python3 run:

```
python3 unicode_to_html.py 
3.7.2 (default, Mar 19 2019, 10:33:22) 
[Clang 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)]
0.24.2
<class 'str'>
...snip...
      <td>BOVÉR, LIÙSAIDH</td>
...snip...
```

Comment: Lol... how did I not notice this was from 2015?! Well there you are.